# Setting up VLAN for Linksys router

Tags: vlan

My Linksys router supports VLANs and I want to set up one to separate my work laptop's connection from my home PC's and devices; however, the Linksys WebUI asks for a [profile](https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=205502) that is specific to various ISPs.

Do I need to contact my ISP to get this info, as I can't find much on YouTube or via a google search?

Comment: That doesn't sound like *the* VLAN *you want*. Even if this router does support what you want (which I doubt), you are looking at the wrong configuration page/section/tab.

Comment: Linksys VLAN makes a second connection to your ISP (sharing the existing fabric) and uses one connection for your laptop and the other for your other devices.  if you don't need separate billing for your laptop's internet usage, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: AFAIK, Linksys OEM firmware doesn't support vLANs in this way. Almost all Linksys routers are [supported](https://openwrt.org/supported_devices) by OpenWrt, which Is the firmware I'd recommend over the OEM firmware for multitude of reasons - in general, OEM firmware hobbles routers from having full functionality _(such as this)_, only supports devices for 1 - 2 yrs, after which security updates are stopped _(OpenWrt releases at least two updates per year, whereas Linksys may only release one per year for one or two years depending on the device)_, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page you show is for if your provider uses a VLAN (ID) for your WAN connection (as well as interface/port setup for VOIP and IPTV), this is not what you want. So you don't need to select a profile or contact your ISP. If your internet/VoIP/IPTV has been working there is nothing you need to do.

For network separation using a single internet connection, you would normally use a VLAN (switch) in combination with a firewall (e.g. pfSence) which allows the separate networks to access the internet (your router) but not each other. Schematically it would look, for example, like this:

[image]

**Addition:**

As Tom Yan suggested, there might be another item in the config menu of your router. If not, your router does not support sharing one internet connection while separating the networks (ports). Or as JW0914 suggested in his comment use OpenWrt if your router is compatible (some manual configuration might be necessary though like setting up the VLANs, subnets, firewall rules, etc., not sure if OpenWrt can do this "out of the box", unless you can use s.th like a guest network, etc.).

PS. A big leap (and this shouldn't work) try to set different VLAN IDs for interface/port 3 and 4 (untagged), for example, 100 and 200, that should separate them from each other but (hopefully) they still will be able to access the internet (probable not since you would have to set a VLAN ID to the WAN port as well).

Comment: thanks.  I might try a few settings changes, but also might be shopping for a new router. I think there are a few ASUS routers that support this.